Ubuntu 24.04 setup not finishing
I was trying to do a clean installation on a computer that was running version 22 without problems. The PC is an HP ProDesk desktop.
I have tried with internet connection on and off... with proprietary software/media support both selected or not.
The installation setup starts and sometime later I get an error and the installation stops.
"System program problem detected"
"Do you want to report the problem now?"

After this I can do nothing and the installation does not continue. If I restart the computer it does nothing... Black screen.

Did you check the hash of the downloaded ISO before installing it to your install media?

Hi. No I didn't. How can I do that?

I used Balena Etcher to flash the USB device. The same as I did on the past for Ubuntu 22. I have tried to install 24.04 also on my Lenovo x230. Same result. Near the end I get the error.
